# using linux shell script insert dump data to Mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

i use below script for insert data to sql from textpad.

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql --utest -ptest test << EOF

LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt'
    INTO TABLE content_delivery_process
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

EOF
```

in my test file i have a format like,

```
cast  ,    date   ,   name   ,   buy
```

i can insert but i need format like below,

```
 S.NO    |   date    |    name    |    buy    |    cast
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the columns you want to import:

From the MySQL Manual:

[MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

> The following example loads all columns of the persondata table:
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata;
> ```
>
> By default, when no column list is provided at the end of the LOAD
>   DATA INFILE statement, input lines are expected to contain a field for
>   each table column.
>
> If you want to load only some of a table's columns, specify a column
>   list:
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata (col1,col2,...);
> ```
>
> You must also specify a column list if the order of the fields in the
>   input file differs from the order of the columns in the table.
>   Otherwise, MySQL cannot tell how to match input fields with table
>   columns.

You would include "FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';" at the end to import data delimited with a '|' symbol.

Comment: Thanks tron. i got it,but after insert i have some problem. In this table i add "S.No" also. but in checking process i run script in twice. hear i got out put only in S.No (1,2,3,4-->fist time i run script) (1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9-->2nd time). plz help this one why that gap(5)? thanks.

Comment: After the load command have you checked the warnings with the following command: SHOW WARNINGS to see if any of your rows had a problem importing?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
create table [YOUR TABLE]  ( `S.NO` INT AUTO_INCREMENT, date DATETIME, name VARCHAR(50), buy VARCHAR(50), cast VARCHAR(50));
Load data local infile 'test.txt' ignore into table  [YOUR TABLE] fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n'(cast , date , name , buy);
```